# Provide a way to search for closed questions by a specific close reason

Tags: feature-request, search, close-reasons

I can search for of all the questions that have been closed for any reason with `closed:1`, but you very rarely want to see just closed questions, you usually care about questions closed for a specific reason.

This would also be a *great* feature for teaching new people about why questions get closed. It would make it very easy pull up a list of questions closed as "subjective and argumentative" to use for examples, giving them the best possible idea of why certain questions are closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Google to find closed questions. Try the following:

To search for posts closed as `Not Constructive`:

1. Go to [Google](http://google.com).
2. Type in:

> `"closed as not constructive" site:stackoverflow.com -site:meta.stackoverflow.com`

This makes sure that none of the results come from `meta.stackoverflow.com`. You can remove that if you want to see `meta` results as well. You can also change the close reason; just make sure the text exactly matches what is usually displayed to the end user.

#### Updated search for 2014:

`"put on hold as" site:stackoverflow.com -site:meta.stackoverflow.com`

#### Sample Search:

[`http://www.google.com/search?q="closed as not constructive" site:stackoverflow.com -site:meta.stackoverflow.com`](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=closed+as+subjective+and+argumentative&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=meta&num=10&lr=&as_filetype=&ft=i&as_sitesearch=stackoverflow.com&as_qdr=all&as_rights=&as_occt=any&cr=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&safe=images)

Comment: great ssolution! now we just need to persuade SO to implement it themselves :D

Comment: We also need SO to implement Overflow Reduction.

Comment: Much better query: `"closed as subjective and argumentative" -site:meta.stackoverflow.com site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 5):

We now have a much improve close tab in the `/review` section ... visible to 10k users only.

[image: close]

This allows you to easily cut through the various questions needing closing.

Comment: pity that it's only for the 10k people. It probably shouldn't be available to everyone, but I don't see why making it available at 3k would hurt anything. Thanks for answering! :D

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer feel free to post a meta question, I think there is a massive hole between 5k and 10k, perhaps we should slot it in at 7.5k