# Page Breaks with really long URLs

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Post Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5460/post-overflow)

See: [Provide a way to search for closed questions by a specific close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33451/search-for-questions-closed-for-a-specific-reason)

If I were to make a really long URL, it goes way off into never-never-land:

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=closed+as+subjective+and+argumentative&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=meta&num=10&lr=&as_filetype=&ft=i&as_sitesearch=stackoverflow.com&as_qdr=all&as_rights=&as_occt=any&cr=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&safe=images

I'm not exactly sure how you would give it proper line breaks, But it is indeed a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I would fix it by editing and replacing it with a text link along the lines of [**Google Search Results**](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=closed+as+subjective+and+argumentative&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=meta&num=10&lr=&as_filetype=&ft=i&as_sitesearch=stackoverflow.com&as_qdr=all&as_rights=&as_occt=any&cr=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&safe=images).

Comment: Yes, I could avoid the bug. But, that doesn't change the fact that it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Webkit and IE seem to ignore the ".post-text" class width being 660px.