# Get a list of questions closed as *too localised*?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide a way to search for closed questions by a specific close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33451/provide-a-way-to-search-for-closed-questions-by-a-specific-close-reason)

Based on [this discussion on Meta The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-far-to-go-with-too-localized), I wonder if it's possible (with limited reputation) to get a list of all questions that were closed as too localised on a specific site. That would be interesting base material for either discussions on beta sites, or for me as a user to decide whether a question I'm going to ask is likely too localised or not.

**Is there any way to get a list of questions closed as too localised?**

Comment: No, unfortunately. You could use SEDE, but 1) it doesn't include betas and 2) hasn't been updated in awhile (but weekly updates will be available in 6-8 weeks).

Comment: Shall I change this into a feature-request then?

Comment: A feature request for what? An easy way to sort closures per close reason perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the assistance of Google.

For a full answer, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33456/172266).